# No sound output device detected all of a sudden

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, sound, devices

Was using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and all of a sudden there was no sound coming from my laptop speakers or earphones.

```
aplay -l
```

output is:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

for`alsamixer`
output is:
 [alsamixer image click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rywai.png)

under system settings sound settings output tab there are no devices listed

reboot doesn't work.
I updated to 16.04 LTS, stil doesn't work

I have also tried `sudo alsa force-reload` but doesn't work

please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out my internal sound card stopped working. I'v been using an external sound card for the last 10 months or so :p